# How to parse tags with namespaces in RSS feed <site:content>

Tags: php, xml, rss

I have a problem with parsing RSS feed with including namespaces. I'm using PHP for this scenario and all other filed are parsed properly.

The only one with problems is description in RSS feed this tag is `<job:description>`.

Any advice will be much appreciated!

```
<?php

    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://careers.pageuppeople.com/671/cw/en-us/rss');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
                    $item = array ( 
                                    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                                    'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS("http://careers.pageuppeople.com/671/cw/en-us/rss","description")->item(0)->nodeValue,
                                    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                                    'pubDate' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                                    'closeDate' => $node->getElementsByTagName('closingDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                                    'field_city' => $node->getElementsByTagName('location')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                                    );
                    array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 5;
    echo '<?xml/>';
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
                    echo '<item>';
                    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
                    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
                    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
                    $field_city = $feed[$x]['field_city'];
                    $pubDate = date('Y: m: d', strtotime($feed[$x]['pubDate']));
                    $closeDate = date('Y: m: d', strtotime($feed[$x]['closeDate']));
                    echo '<title>'.$title.'</title>';
                    echo '<pubDate>'.$pubDate.'</pubDate>';
                    echo '<closeDate> '.$closeDate.'</closeDate>';
                    echo '<link>'.$link.'</link>';
                    echo '<field_city>'.$field_city.'</field_city>';
                    echo '<body>'.$description.'</body>';
                    echo '<field_how_to_apply><strong>UNICEF is committed to diversity and inclusion within its workforce, and encourages qualified female and male candidates from all national, religious and ethnic backgrounds, including persons living with disabilities, to apply to become a part of our organization.<br><br>To apply click on the link below.</strong><br><br>'.$link.'</field_how_to_apply>';
                    echo '</item>';

    }

    echo '</channel></rss>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a wrong NameSpaceURI. You can find NameSpaceURIs searching for `xmlns:prefix` in a parent node of namespaced node (generally, in the root node).

In your case:

```
<channel xmlns:job="http://pageuppeople.com/">
```

So you have to use correct NSURI:

```
(...)
'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS("http://pageuppeople.com/","description")->item(0)->nodeValue,
(...)
```

and your script wil work.

Comment: Works like a charm Thank you very much !